# Github Actions - PHPUnit & MySQL Incredibly slow

Tags: php, mysql, docker, phpunit, github-actions

I'm trying to setup Github Actions to run our test suite, using PHPUnit and a MySQL database. I've got it setup but it's incredibly slow, each individual test taking a minimum 10-15 seconds, while normally the entire test suite takes around 27 seconds.

I've tried using a proper [Mysql](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-mysql) action as well as changing the ports, nothing worked.

My reduced workfile file is below...

```yaml
name: Laravel

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.6
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: testing
        ports:
          - 33306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
      - name: Execute tests
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit
        env:
          DB_PORT: 3306
          DB_USERNAME: root
          DB_PASSWORD: password
          DB_DATABASE: testing
          DB_HOST: mysql
```

Thank you!

Comment: How many tests are there in the suite?  How fast does running 1/3 of the tests?

Comment: can you put your test code here? if you are seeding the db in each test and you have many tables or data that would be normal to me, because, in each test run it will create all tables and insert all data (seeders).

Comment: I can't add the tests, but no it doesn't seed data, and the entire test suite runs in 27s normally, it's just the Github Action that's show.